# int.TryParse vs. other methods for determining if a char contains an int

Tags: c#, tryparse

When using the `char` datatype is there any reason one should use `int.TryParse`

```
int.TryParse(inputChar.ToString(), NumberStyles.Integer, 
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out curNum)
```

vs.

```
inputChar - '0'
```

And checking if the result is between `0-9`?

Comment: Can you please clarify the question - as it reads, it's very difficult to understand what's being asked

Comment: Well, what about when you don't have a `char`, but a string containing the value `"192384"`? How would you subtract `0`? Also, while that may work in "our" cultural environment, the thing about different cultures and character sets is that the character code for `0` may not in all cases be smaller than the character code of every other number.

Comment: Oh I see. You're talking about the case where it is only a single `char` not a string.

Comment: What's unclear about the question? The OP asks why he should use a standard library function to parse an integer rather than doing his own conversion the usual hacky way. It might be considered off-topic for SO, but what's unclear about it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if a `char` is a *digit* you should use [`Char.IsDigit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
if (Char.IsDigit(inputChar))
{ 
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Looks like that includes additional unicode characters outside of Ascii `0-9` so I suppose it depends what the OP requires this for.

Comment: @MartinSmith: normally it just checks `c >= '0' && c <= '9'` with [latin-1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537495(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: `Char.IsDigit('۵')` is true for example. Haven't tested if that is the same semantics as the `int.parse` shown in the question.

Comment: @MartinSmith: i assume if you need to fiddle around with such characters you also need it to be a digit/number. So either this doesn't matter because you aren't using them or it would be incorrect to check only `c >= '0' && c <= '9'`.

Comment: @MartinSmith: by the way, since i've looked at the regex approach you have linked in the other answer, interestingly it returns the same list of 310 characters as `Char.IsDigit`.

Comment: And it appears these are not the same as are accepted by `[Try]Parse` unless I miss some option? e.g. `int.Parse("３", NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` returns an error rather than 3.

Answer (score 0):

Well, two reasons why *I* would always use `TryParse`

1. Using a well-tested library function is always better than re-inventing the wheel.
2. The world outside the US doesn't speak "ASCII" - so there might be cases when the character code for `0` is not the smallest for a digit. In that case `'9' - '0' != 9;`. This is a *might be*. And because I'm too lazy to google this I'm on the safe side using `TryParse` :-)

Comment: @MartinSmith I wonder: How can it be the accepted answer to the question you quoted has been upvoted 1068 times, but the person who wrote the answer only has 6371 reputation?

Comment: Rep cap. Probably many of those 1000 votes were all on the same few days.

Comment: Oh, see? I didn't know that. That's a shame, really. Assume I answer 5 questions today and each answer is upvoted 10 times today, I still get only 200 points... Well, most probably this has been discussed on meta extensively ;-)

Answer (score -1):

That's only about code clarity. `int.TryParse` clearly states its intent - I want to parse the string as number, if possible. It's relatively fast and safe.

If you find yourself getting stuck on `TryParse`s, you can always write your own parsing. In some cases, it can save significant amount of time. For example, I've done such an implementation when parsing DBFs, which otherwise induced a lot of overhead from parsing bytes to strings, and strings to ints. Directly converting from the stream to int saved a lot of allocations and time.

After all, if you don't want to use built-in methods, why use .NET at all? Why not write everything in machine code? :))

Comment: Now that the question has been clarified I am willing and able to remove my comments :-)